# Static background behind the whole page

Tags: css

I know it's a stupid title but I have no way to Google this because I don't know how it's called.

Basically if you go to Skrill's website https://www.skrill.com/en/merchants/ and you scroll down, the background itself stays, while the elements are transparent on top of it.

How is this called and what are some CSS rules I can look into to do this?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqdXRp

Comment: this - https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ - every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Chrome, you can 'inspect' (in right-click menu) while on a website to see what the CSS properites are. The website you reference has a div with the class full-background-container and inside that is a div with the background image and it's positioned fixed. What you are seeing on that website is "parallax" - the movement is CSS + JS positioning during scroll events.

Comment: Omg the other answers are correct, but it was exactly the word "Parallax" that I was looking for. I think I can Google it from here. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

`background-attachment` property is what you are looking for...

Example:

```
body  {
    background-image: url('some_image.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```